# Number of unramified extension of f $ \Bbb{Q}_p$ of given degree is $1$, correct?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory

Number of unramified extension of $ \Bbb{Q}_p$ of given degree is $1$, correct ?

I may made some misunderstanding.Îs my following argument correct?

$ \Bbb {Q}_p$($p$ is odd prime) has $p＋1$ extensions from local class field theory, and there is only one unramified extension because there is bijection between 'unramified extension of local field of degree $n$' and 'Corresponding extension of residue field of degree $n$'.But for given $n$, there is only one degree $n$ extension of residue field.
So, I conclude there is only one unramified extension of degree $n$, and other $n-1$ extensions ramify(may totally ramify, someone not).

Comment: There is indeed just one unramified extension of each degree over $\mathbf Q_p$ (or of any other non-Archimedean local field) in an algebraic closure. But this does not at all require local class field theory, and if you are focusing on local class field theory then you might only be paying attention to abelian extensions. For example, what do you mean when you say $\mathbf Q_p$ has $p+1$ extensions? It has infinitely many finite extensions: its algebraic closure is in fact an infinite-degree extension of $\mathbf Q_p$. There are *not* $n$ extensions of degree $n$.

Comment: For example, $\mathbf Q_p$ has $3$ extensions of degree $2$ for $p>2$ and $7$ extensions of degree $2$ for $p=2$.